# events listing "no layouts found" after WP upgrade

Tags: wordpress, civievent

After upgrading from 4.7.10 to 4.7.24 having problems displaying events on public pages
eg https://leep.ngo/civicrm/?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/event/register&reset=1&id=1881
or 
https://leep.ngo/civicrm/?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/event/ical&reset=1&list=1&html=1

Page is correct site template but page is blank - message is "no layouts found"

Was working fine pre-upgrade
ALSO works fine if I revert to standard twenty sixteen template.
Theme developer is hard to contact and I don't know much about WP but can anyone indicate what the upgrade might have changed 
cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The theme developer fixed it. His explanation:

"We have updated and fixed that issue. The previous script was detecting a URL structure and would display that particular template, it seemed the URL structure had changed"

doesn't mean much to me but maybe will help others